# Altering JSON column to INTEGER[] ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a JSON column that contains an array of integers. I am trying to convert it to an INTEGER[] column, but I'm running into casting errors.

Here's my final alter version:

`ALTER TABLE namespace_list ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids TYPE INTEGER[] USING string_to_array(namespace_ids::integer[], ',');`

However, this throws this error:
`ERROR:  cannot cast type json to integer[]`

Any ideas how I can abouts this conversion? I've tried several things but I end up with the same error. Seems like going json --> string --> --> array does not work. What are my options?

**Edit:**

Table definition:

```
db => \d+ namespace_list;

Column         |   Type   |  Table "kiwi.namespace_list" Modifiers|
---------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
id             | integer  | not null default nextval('namespace_list_id_seq'::regclass)
namespace_ids  | json     | not null default '[]'::json
```

Sample data:

```
id | namespace_ids | 
-------------------+
1 | [1,2,3]        |
```

Comment: Providing a table definition and a few sample values would be the polite thing to do ..

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Table definition added; pretty much what was described (a JSON column), and sample data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming no invalid characters in your array.

IN Postgres **9.4** or later use a conversion function as outlined here:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_arr2int_arr(_js json)
  RETURNS int[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(_js)::int)';

ALTER TABLE namespace_list
  ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids DROP DEFAULT
, ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids TYPE int[] USING json_arr2int_arr(namespace_ids);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9421fc7f1539cea4f7ce48b9cecd60b6)*

---

For Postgres **9.3** or older:

```
ALTER TABLE namespace_list
ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids TYPE INTEGER[]
      USING translate(namespace_ids::text, '[]','{}')::int[];
```

The specific difficulty is that you cannot have a subquery expression in the `USING` clause, so unnesting & re-aggregating is *not an option*:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT(json_array_elements(json_col)::text::int))
FROM   namespace_list;
```

Therefore, I resort to string manipulation to produce a valid string constant for an integer array and cast it.

#### column `DEFAULT`

If there is a column default like `DEFAULT '[]'::json` in your actual table definition added later, drop it *before* you do the above.
You can add a new `DEFAULT` afterwards if you need one. Best in the same transaction (or even command):

```sql
ALTER TABLE namespace_list
   ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids DROP DEFAULT
,  ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids TYPE INT[] USING translate(namespace_ids::text, '[]','{}')::int[]
,  ALTER COLUMN namespace_ids SET DEFAULT '{}';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8fbfb075345b1bab1495865828f32a9b)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2352d)</sub>

Comment: I still get `ERROR:  default for column "namespace_ids" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[]`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Nayefc: Goes to show the importance of the table definition. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: This works, thanks! I guess '[]'::json cannot be cast into an array using this way? Any reason why?

Comment: @Nayefc: It can be cast just the same way, but the default clause is part of the *table definition*, which is another matter altogether.