# cannot cast type character varying[] to jsonb django migration

Tags: python, django, model, migration

I have alter my model from arrayfield to json field now i am receiving error

> cannot cast type character varying[] to jsonb
>   LINE 1: ...LUMN "questionaires" TYPE jsonb USING "questionaires"::jsonb.

How to fix this ? and how it did occur?

from

```
questionaires   = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=4000), null=True, blank=True)
```

to

```
questionaires   = JSONField(null = True,blank = True)
```

Comment: Django can not convert the data inside your `questionaires` field from array to json. Do you have already some data inside your model/relation? If not, you could try remove the `ArrayField`, `migrate`, add the new `JSONField` and `migrate` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to perform multiple stage migrates:

1. Create temporary new field with type JSONField: Ex questionaires_2
2. Write custom python migration [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) to convert data manually
3. Delete old field: questionaires
4. Rename temporary field to the old one questionaires_2 -> questionaires

More advance: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21997589/533738

Not tested!!!

```
ALTER TABLE <Your Table>
ALTER COLUMN questionaires TYPE JSONB
      USING translate(questionaires::text, '{}','[]')::JSONB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my code while changing a field type from Array to a JSON. The job is done in 3 steps. First, you have to delete all data from related table to model; In case you using postgreSql as your database:

```
    DELETE FROM 'app_name'_'model_name';
```

Second, run the following code to delete all migrations you've done to your app from database:

```
    DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='app_name';
```

Third, delete all the migrations from migrations subfolder in your app except the `__init__.py` file.

If it didn't work for you instead of step 1 you can run this code to delete entire table and build it from the beginning, and then do the rest:

```
    DROP TABLE 'app_name'_'model_name';
```