# Construct ARRAY of values from a subquery in Postgres and use it in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, subquery, jsonb

These are samples of the two tables I have:

**Table 1**

```
  material_id (int)        codes (jsonb)        
---------------------    -------------------------------      
        1                  ['A-12','B-19','A-14','X-22']           
        2                  ['X-106','A-12','X-22','B-19']        
        .
        .
```

**Table 2**

```
   user_id        material_list (jsonb)
 -----------    --------------------
     1                 [2,3]
     2                 [1,2]
     .
     .
```

Table 1 contains material IDs and an array of codes associated with that material.

Table 2 contains user IDs. Each user has a list of materials associated with it and this is saved an an array of material IDs

I want to fetch a list of user IDs for all materials having certain codes. This is the query I tried, but it threw a syntax error:

```
SELECT user_id from table2
WHERE material_list ?| array(SELECT material_id 
                             FROM table1 where codes ?| ['A-12','B-19]);
```

I am unable to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: What results do you want?  The question is not 100% clear.

Comment: Please make it a habit to disclose the verbatim error message. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query fails for multiple reasons.

First, `['A-12','B-19]` isn't a valid Postgres text array. Either use an array constant or an array constructor:

```
'{A-12,B-19}'
ARRAY['A-12','B-19']
```

See:

- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)
- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)

Next, the operator `?|` demands `text[]` to the right, while you provide `int[]`.

Finally, it wouldn't work anyway, as the operator `?|` checks for JSON *strings*, not *numbers*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?

Convert the JSON array to a Postgres integer array, then use the [array overlap operator  **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM   tbl2
WHERE  ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(material_list)::int)
    && ARRAY(SELECT material_id FROM tbl1 where codes ?| array['A-12','B-19']);
```

I strongly suggest to alter your table to convert the JSON array in `material_list` to a Postgres integer array (`int[]`) for good. See:

- [Altering JSON column to INTEGER[] ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996773/altering-json-column-to-integer-array/21997589#21997589)
- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Then the query gets simpler:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   tbl2
WHERE  material_list && ARRAY(SELECT material_id FROM tbl1 where codes ?| '{A-12,B-19}');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e25897b9fd6f1aa2d5563bea9556844)*

Or - dare I say it? - properly **normalize** your relational design. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the process of unnesting json arrays:

```
select t2.user_id
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1  join 
                   jsonb_array_elements_text(t2.material_list) j(material_id)
                   on t1.material_id = j.material_id::int join
                   jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.codes) j2(code)
                   on j2.code in ('A-12', 'B-19')
             );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd050e1f1c5c1005927795f145c4d989) is a db<>fiddle.